# Write a Shell Script for sending email on Disk Space Full - integer expression expected?

Tags: shell, sh

New to Shell Scripting.

I am getting following exception while executing SH Script:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root: integer  expression expected
/ 5.2G
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /: integer expression expected
29% /dev/xvda1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-home
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-home: integer expression expected
/home 5.2G
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /home: integer expression expected
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-opt
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-opt: integer expression expected
/opt 5.3G
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /opt: integer expression expected
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var: integer expression expected
/var 5.3G
./DiskSpace.sh: line 7: [: /var: integer expression expected
```

Following is script i am trying to execute:

```
#!/bin/sh
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' |   while read output;
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
if [ $usep -ge 90 ]; then
  echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" |
  mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" azrael@opinkerfi.com
fi
done
```

Following is output of df -h on linux system:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root
                  4.8G  1.9G  2.7G  42% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            194M   52M  132M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-home
                  4.9G  1.9G  2.8G  41% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-opt
                  5.0G  4.4G  360M  93% /opt
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var
                  5.0G  3.7G  1.1G  78% /var
```

Comment: First: Use `set -x` see the commands as executed, with their actual values substituted (or `bash -x yourscript`). Second: Keep in mind that POSIX sh only requires support for integer math; floating-point values are only supported by shells with appropriate extensions (which includes ksh93 and zsh, but not bash).

Comment: ...in general, `foo=$(echo $bar | awk ...)` is an antipattern, unless you're really, really sure it can't be done with builtins. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 for a taste of the functionality available natively.

Comment: (though `echo $bar` is itself an antipattern, buggy compared to `echo "$bar"`).

Comment: Actually, given the output you quoted, one immediate cause (if your `df` still behaves the same way when output is not to a TTY) is obvious: You have lines where the filesystem is on a different line from the size, percentage, etc; that's going to throw your data off badly. Using the `-P` argument to `df`, forcing POSIX-compliant output, will prevent that.

Comment: @Charles: After executing set -x i am continuesly getting line on each enter. How can i remove that?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, if you use it in an interactive shell. However, you should be putting `set -x` in the script you want to trace, or running `bash -x scriptname` to invoke said script. Use `set +x` to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest moving most of your logic here out of external commands and into the shell itself; the performance savings from eliminating all the unnecessary calls to awk, grep, &c. will more than save the extra cost of starting bash instead of /bin/sh.

As for the bug immediately at hand, make sure your values are actually integers. That means removing not only the % sign, but also any decimal points. Also, use `df -P`, to ensure POSIX-compliant output (which will ensure that your column numbers are in fact what and where you think they are).

```
#!/bin/bash
ignore_re='^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom'
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line ]] || continue # skip empty lines
  [[ $line =~ $ignore_re ]] && continue
  read -r filesystem blocks_total blocks_used blocks_avail cap_pct mounted_at _ <<<"$line"
  # below is a noop but makes set -x output more useful
  : filesystem="$filesystem" blocks_total="$blocks_total" blocks_used="$blocks_used" blocks_avail="$blocks_avail" cap_pct="$cap_pct" mounted_at="$mounted_at"
  usep=${cap_pct%"%"} # trim trailing % sign
  usep=${usep%.*}     # round (down) to nearest decimal
  if (( usep >= 90 )); then
    mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" azrael@opinkerfi.com <<EOF
$filesystem (mounted on $mounted_at) usage is $usep on $(hostname) as of $(date)
EOF
  fi
done < <(df -P)
```

If your shell is bash 4.1 or newer, you can also eliminate the external call to `$(date)` in favor of printf's new `%()T` builtin for calling `strftime`.

Comment: Tried to run this script but unable to get output. I tried to run bash -x yourscript; that keep on showing -> + read -r line

+ [[ '' =~ ^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom ]]
+ read filesystem blocks_total blocks_used blocks_avail cap_pct mounted_at _
+ usep=
+ usep=
+ ((  usep >= 90  ))

Comment: Hmm. That means that it's actually getting empty lines from `df`, if that's literally the only thing it shows.

Comment: (the `[[ '' =~ ...regex here... ]]` is the giveaway, since the left-hand side is `$line`).

Comment: That said -- could you put the **full** output of running with `bash -x` in http://gist.github.com/ -- and perhaps a copy-and-paste of the script precisely as you're running it? (a single gist can contain multiple files).

Comment: I have never used github. I am sharing it to JSFIDDLE. i know it is weird as it is for HTML/Javascript -> https://jsfiddle.net/2oo2o5dc/

Comment: What you shared there is missing the `< <(df -P)` -- rather a critical component. Note that my answer has been edited several times since it was first posted; do be sure you're using a current version.

Comment: Also able to achieve it with your suggestion the other way i posted in question :). Thanks for great help